# Question marks appears when I input UNIX user account

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, username

After I downloaded ubuntu from microsoft store, many question marks appear. Can anyone help me out here? I also can not create a unix user account. Thanks.
[Error with ????,???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pNEB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes an issue related to the font being used in the terminal, particularly if that font does not support UTF-8 characters. Try changing the font to something else to see if the question marks disappear.